# Robomongo doesn't seem to update documents

Tags: c#, mongodb, robo3t

I am writing a web application using C# and MongoDB. In order to update a document I have written a code looking like this:

```
public MyType Update(MyType obj) {
    ...
    var oFilter = Builders<MyType>.Filter.Eq(o => o.MyId, obj.MyId);
    var oResult = oCollection.FindOneAndReplace(oFilter, obj);
    if(oResult!=null)
        Console.Writeline("object to update found");
    ...
    return oResult;
}
```

The class MyType looks like this

```
[DataContract]
public class MyType
{
    [DataMember(Name="_id")]
    [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(CombGuidGenerator))]
    public Guid MyId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The code basically compares the _id of obj with the _id of every document of the collection, and if it finds a match it performs the update. The program seems to run smoothly but when I check Robomongno the object isn't updated, even when the object to update has been found.

Comment: I have just found out that it updates the first document of the collection.

Answer (score 0):

You are using FindOneAndReplace which MongoDB says "finds a single document and replaces atomically" which is why you update the first one. What you probably need is and `UpdateMany()` so perhaps

```
    public MyType Update(MyType obj) {
        ...
        var oFilter = Builders<MyType>.Filter.Eq(o => o.MyId, obj.MyId);
        var oResult = oCollection.UpdateMany(
                                 { o.MyId: obj.MyId },
                                 { $set: { "MyFieldName" : MyValue} }

                                             );
        if(oResult!=null)
            Console.Writeline("object to update found");
        ...
        return oResult;
    }
```

but I am not sure how to use the UpdateMany() method.
Check out https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/